# Select the newest sets of rows in a set of data where they share a FK

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a set of data that has the following layout:

```
SPECNUMBER | CHANGEDATE | CHANGE
1          | 01/01/2019 | zzz
1          | 01/01/2019 | xxx
1          | 01/01/2019 | vvv
1          | 30/07/2019 | yyy
1          | 30/07/2019 | uuu
1          | 30/07/2019 | www
2          | 01/01/2019 | zzz
2          | 01/01/2019 | xxx
2          | 01/01/2019 | vvv
2          | 22/07/2019 | yyy
2          | 22/07/2019 | uuu
2          | 22/07/2019 | www`
```

I would like to return only the newest set so only the bottom 3 rows of each specnumber in the example above are returned, so that the resulting dataset would look like this:

```
SPECNUMBER | CHANGEDATE | CHANGE
1          | 30/07/2019 | yyy
1          | 30/07/2019 | uuu
1          | 30/07/2019 | www
2          | 22/07/2019 | yyy
2          | 22/07/2019 | uuu
2          | 22/07/2019 | www`
```

I've attempted to use MAX(changedate) however my implementation of this resulted in only returning the largest changedate in the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `rank()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by SPECNUMBER order by CHANGEDATE desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: This was it! Well done. Seems a useful tool, i'll remember this one.